# Assist me in finding the error?

Tags: c, string, embedded, structure, rtems

I am working on the interface (RS232) for communication between aeroflex gaisler hardware (RTEMS operating system and leon2 processor) and the desktop terminal. I have written a code for communication between them. I am getting a error in all the function calls, if anyone had experienced this kind of problem then please help me to fix it.

NOTE: I am not able to upload my code here.

```
ERRORS:  expected `)` before `hserial`
         expected `)` before `hserial`
         expected `)` before `hserial`
         expected `=``,`,`;`,`,`asm`or'_attribute_` before `openserialport`
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "serial-com.h"
#include <drvmgr/drvmgr.h>
#include <rtems.h>
#include <ioctl.h>
#include <apbuart.h>

HANDLE openSerialPort(LPCSTR portname, DWORD accessdirection){
//  HANDLE hSerial = CreateFile(portname,
//          accessdirection,
//          0,
//          0,
//          OPEN_EXISTING,
//          0,
//          0);
    HANDLE hSerial = CreateFile("/dev/rastaio2/apbuart1", O_RDWR);

    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        //call GetLastError(); to gain more information
    }

    return hSerial;
}

void setComPortConfig(HANDLE hSerial){

    COMMCONFIG dcbSerialParams;

    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb))
    {
        printf("error getting state \n");
    }

    dcbSerialParams.dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams.dcb);

    dcbSerialParams.dcb.BaudRate = 9600;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;

    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fDsrSensitivity= FALSE;
    dcbSerialParams.dcb.fAbortOnError = TRUE;

    if (!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams.dcb))
    {
        printf(" error setting serial port state \n");
    }
}

void setComPortTimeouts(HANDLE hSerial){
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    GetCommTimeouts(hSerial,&timeouts);

    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier= 10;
}

DWORD writeToSerialPort(HANDLE hSerial, char *data, int length)
{
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 1;
    if(!WriteFile(hSerial, data, length, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
        //printLastError();
    }
    return dwBytesRead;

}

DWORD readFromSerialPort(HANDLE hSerial, char *h, int size)
{
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 1;
   if(!ReadFile(hSerial, h, size, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
        //handle error
    }
    return dwBytesRead;
}

void closeSerialPort(HANDLE hSerial)
{
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
}
```

Header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ioctl.h>
#include <apbuart.h>
#include <rtems.h>
#include <drvmgr/drvmgr.h>

HANDLE openSerialPort(LPCSTR portname, DWORD accessdirection);

DWORD writeToSerialPort(HANDLE hSerial, char *data, int length);

DWORD readFromSerialPort(HANDLE hSerial, char *buffer, int length);

void setComPortConfig(HANDLE hSerial);

void setComPortTimeouts (HANDLE hSerial);

void closeSerialPort(HANDLE hSerial);
```

The header file contains a function call and the error I am getting in the function call only. The code contains the function body and I also included the header file in the code. the path for all the remaining header file is also included.

Comment: If you can't show any code or error-messages, people can't help...

Comment: Error in all function??what is error?

Comment: the code consists of several number of .c files which is difficult to upload everything .

Comment: @suhassjbit - posts at least some of the errors

Comment: now I posted some of the errors

Comment: you might forgot `;` or something..

Comment: Could be issues with struct definition.

Comment: post your code snippet which contains `openserialport` and 10 lines above this function `openserialport`

Comment: Please give the line of code where error comes and some lines around that.

Comment: you missed some include file which contains definition for HANDLE, DWORD, etc

Comment: Check inside `#include <apbuart.h>` for some missing symbols, and include `<windows.h> in the beginning line itself.

Comment: it may be a syntax error too.Like missing closing braces, or #ifdef endif(endif without hash) or missed semicolon at hte end of structure definition.

Answer (score 2):

the link below might helps you....

This also contains serial port related operation.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/18720-handle-and-dword-in-serial-programming/

Answer (score 2):

The type `HANDLE` is probably undefined at the point it's occuring, try adding

```
#include <windows.h>
```

around the top of the header.

Comment: I used tat also but its not working